# How to create a dynamic top margin using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to JavaScript and am trying to use it to give my footer a margin. I need the footer to be flush against the bottom of my content, which has a dynamic height (when the browser is resized, the content gets appropriately larger/smaller to fit text). Here's my code:

```js
function footermargin() {
  var height = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
  document.getElementById("footer").style.marginTop = "height";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1000;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: #134;
  margin-top: auto;
  z-index: -9999999;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">this is the content of the webpage. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sed lacus libero. Duis tristique fringilla purus, a blandit arcu lacinia in. Phasellus quis lobortis justo. Proin fringilla nulla nisl, at fringilla metus maximus quis. Donec ultricies fringilla felis, eget rhoncus neque mollis ac. Aliquam porta, odio sed ornare consequat, enim neque pharetra enim, sit amet luctus turpis odio id erat. Vivamus porttitor egestas nunc a maximus. Cras maximus et erat nec tincidunt. Nam eget lectus a lorem rutrum fringilla sit amet in lacus. Vestibulum nec pharetra lectus. Proin non quam quis mauris tempor varius ac eget purus. Quisque luctus leo ut libero sollicitudin, ac fringilla tellus lacinia.
  </div>
  <div id="footer">this is the footer of the webpage. I need this flush against the bottom of the content without using specific margins.</div>
  <script>
    function footermargin() {
      var height = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
      document.getElementById("footer").style.marginTop = "height";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: That sounds like the default behavior ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've pasted your code into a codepen project, so we can get an idea what you want clearly. :)

I've removed `#content {position: absolute;}` from the code, which i think made what you wanted, please check and let me know. If it didn't i will refine my answer :)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaOPmz

Comment: This works, thanks! I had the `position: absolute;` because I thought it was required for centering.

Answer (score 1):

In case you still consider using javascript.

```js
var height = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("footer").style.marginTop = height+"px";
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#content {
  //position: absolute; this line on purpose ?
  z-index: -1000;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: #134;
  margin-top: auto;
  z-index: -9999999;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">this is the content of the webpage. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sed lacus libero. Duis tristique fringilla purus, a blandit arcu lacinia in. Phasellus quis lobortis justo. Proin fringilla nulla nisl, at fringilla metus maximus quis. Donec ultricies fringilla felis, eget rhoncus neque mollis ac. Aliquam porta, odio sed ornare consequat, enim neque pharetra enim, sit amet luctus turpis odio id erat. Vivamus porttitor egestas nunc a maximus. Cras maximus et erat nec tincidunt. Nam eget lectus a lorem rutrum fringilla sit amet in lacus. Vestibulum nec pharetra lectus. Proin non quam quis mauris tempor varius ac eget purus. Quisque luctus leo ut libero sollicitudin, ac fringilla tellus lacinia.
  </div>
  <div id="footer">this is the footer of the webpage. I need this flush against the bottom of the content without using specific margins.</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should force the footer to the bottom.

```
# Note I changed the #content to .content so that it wouldn't be commented out
html, body, .content{ height: 100%;}
body > .content{height: auto; min-height: 100%;}
.content{ padding-bottom: 3em;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Box model  with CSS http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp about your element and use percentage for your div footer so when you use porcetages about the margin or padding in your element this will be always the same. Something like

## footer{padding-bottom:10%;}

http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics This link maybe can help you to learn about elements with JavaScript and CSS